# Local site defaults to webhelper.centurylink.com

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, localhost

I've long used MAMP on my MacBook Pro for web design. However, I recently got hit with some weird bug that I couldn't figure out, so I just upgraded from OS El Capitan to Sierra. I upgraded to the latest MAMP at the same time.

However, I now can't get MAMP to work. I decided to try setting things up without MAMP. Eventually, I'd like to migrate my website to a traditional "sites" folder. So I created a new site at user/Sites/g1/index.php.

This is what I have in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName g1
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdoc/g1/index.php">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
# ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried it with this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName g1
DocumentRoot "/Users/[My Username]/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/[My Username]/Sites/g1/index.php">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
# ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know anything about Apache error logs, so I just commented that line out.

I Googled for help and found a discussion that suggested I add the following line to httpd.conf, so I did:

ServerName local_server:80

I haven't modified the/etc/hosts file, which looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
```

I should mention that I haven't uninstalled MAMP, though it isn't running. I did open it to see if it might work after all the changes I've made, but it still doesn't work. But when I navigate to http://localhost, I get a MAMP page that says "The virtual host was set up correctly."

Actually, with my most recent changes - and with MAMP turned off -
 http://localhost now displays the directory @ username/Sites/g1. I can view the same thing at http://127.0.0.1.

If I type in http://localhost:80, it defaults to http://localhost. http://localhost:8888 doesn't work (except perhaps if MAMP is running).

In the httpd.conf file, I changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All, then I restarted Apache. However, nothing changed, so I changed it back.

I added a page at Sites > g1 > index.php. I discovered that I can access it @ http://localhost/~[My Username]/ But if I change the URL to http://g1, it still defaults to http://webhelper.centurylink.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//g1/&r=&bc=

When I type apachectl configtest into Terminal, all it says is "Syntax OK." So I suspect I just need a little tweak here or there.

On the other hand, I found some web pages that suggest webhelper is some sort of scam. So I ran Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, but it didn't find any problems.

Before I spend any more time on that can of worms, can anyone spot a specific problem in the code I've posted above?

P.S. This is sort of a continuation of [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/1215795/local-site-defaults-to-https), which I started before I upgraded to OS Sierra and the current MAMP PRO version.

**EDIT:**

I just created a second folder in my Sites folder named g2. I can now view two sites at http://localhost/~[My Username]/g1/ and http://localhost/~[My Username]/g2/

But when I replaced the temporary folder g1 with the original, it resumed defaulting to https. I created a temporary folder named z - just a folder with a single index.php page and one line of plain text. It defaults to https, too.

So I'm apparently dealing with the same problem I had before I upgraded to Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have some kind of browser hijacking crap installed if it's interpreting your request for a machine called g1 as a search at centurylink for g1.  Check your extensions and installed search engines (these are in your browser settings) and trash anything you don't recognize, check system prefs->networking and make sure your DNS servers are set to somemthing sane (you shouldn't be using Centurylink, try Google's at 8.8.8.8, for example, there are many other perfectly good options, you should probably be picking up something sane from your ISP.)   You might want to look at a free malware scanner (like, say, malwarebytes).

Comment: I already ran Malwarebytes, but it noted that there could be other problems it didn't catch. I'll check the ISP stuff; that sounds like a good tip.